# How convert a Byte[] to a data to insert a value in a varbinary(max) column in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

I have a object with a `byte[]` property, and I would like to convert this value to the correct value to can insert it into the database using T-SQL.

But I don't know how I could convert the `byte[]` to the correct value for T-SQL for the insert.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a Console Application project and try this code

```
// Sample Class
public class MyClass
{
    public byte[] data;
}

// Main 
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyClass cls = new MyClass();
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("CONNECTION STRING"))
    {
        cn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into MyTable values (@data)", cn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", cls.data);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The overload of `Add` you are calling is marked obsolete. You should use `.AddWithValue("@data", cls.data);` or `.Add("@data", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = cls.data;`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, Thanks for notifying me. I updated my answer

Answer (score 7):

You want to convert to [VarBinary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype(v=vs.110).aspx).

See the following:

[SQL Server Data Type Mappings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

**simple example (setting command parameter)**

```
byte[] data;
command.Parameters.Add("@data", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = data;
```

**T-SQL example of how to pass in varbinary**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE YourStoredProc
    @data varbinary(max)
AS
BEGIN
  -- your code
END
```

Comment: it would be good to show how you use the parameter in the query too, if the OP has never used parameters before he may not know how to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the use of AddWithValue. It helps me.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía that is the wrong way to use AddWithValue, I have corrected it to use the correct function.

Answer (score 5):

Generating raw varbinary to insert to database (copy-paste case)

```
string ToVarbinary(byte[] data)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder((data.Length * 2) + 2);
        sb.Append("0x");

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(data[i].ToString("X2"));
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```